# Excel VBA trying to insert a blank row in cells A2:E2

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a blank row in cells A2:E2

I currently am inserting an entire blank row using
"Rows(2).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown" 
but ideally I would only like to insert a new row in row 2 from columns A to E

Comment: `Range("A2:E2").Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Sub insertRow()

    Range("A2:E2").Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! still getting my bearings in VBA